# Nav Links will not center on my page

Tags: html, css

The issue I am having is that no matter what I try I cannot seem to center my nav bar at all. I am pretty new to the HTML/CSS world and can't figure this one out. If you could take a look and see if you can think of how to center them that would be greatly appreciated!

Here is a picture of the issue:[image]

Part of my HTML CODE:

```
    <title>Neon Angels</title>
</head>

<body class="fix">
    <div id="wrapper">

         <div class="section black" id="section1">
              <h2 id="welcome">The Neon Angels Welcome You!
                  <img src="wingslogo.svg" alt="" id="top">
                  <img src="wingslogo.svg" alt="" id="top2">
             </h2>
             <p>
                  <img src="wings.jpg" alt="wings" width="750" id="wings">
             </p>

             <ul class="nav">
                  <li><a href="#section2" style="text-decoration:none">About Us</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#section3" style="text-decoration:none">Painting with Light</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#section4" style="text-decoration:none">Portraits</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#section5" style="text-decoration:none">Nature</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#section6" style="text-decoration:none">Contact Us</a></li>
             </ul>

            <div class="mouse">
                <div class="mouse-icon">
                   <span class="mouse-wheel"></span>
                </div>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS CODE:

```
.nav{
    padding-left: 250px;
    padding-right: 250px;
    margin-left: 500px;
    width: 1000px;
    list-style: none;
}

.black ul li{
    display:inline;
    color:#aaa;
    float:left;
}
.black ul li a{
    padding:0px 10px; 
    color:#f0f0f0;
}
.black ul li a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #80F9FF;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: aguafina-script;
}

#wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making your `.nav` into this:

```
.nav {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Here's a goofy demo: http://codepen.io/antibland/pen/MyZprK

Comment: won't `top` default to 0 and put the `.nav` at the very top of the page? Maybe wrapping the nav in a containing div with `position:relative;` would solve this?

Comment: I added a demo link for you. Check it out.

Comment: oh nice. I thought it would default to `top: 0;` but it doesn't seem to be doing that.

Comment: Andy what is all that long code of characters in the img src?

Comment: This coding did center my links however it stacked them and I need them to be horizontal in a line. Any ideas?

Comment: @Cakers Make sure you have `white-space: nowrap;` on the `<ul>`. You'll notice that the links in my demo don't stack.

Comment: It worked! thank you so much! this saved me so much time and energy!

Comment: I thought I did, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your code

```
.nav{
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
width: 1000px;
list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `<li>` elements have `float: left`. Remove that property, and `text-align: center` will work! Don't use so much width, margin and padding on `<nav>`, it looks bad on smaller screens!